# What regex to use?

Tags: css, regex, notepad++, rgb

Does anybody know the regular expression code to change any thing similar to `#f2f2f2;` in to `#000000;`. Also the one for `rgb(210, 236, 238);` to `rgb(0, 0, 0);`. I guess you can tell that in a long text file I want to change all colors to black. I am using the Notepad++ Find and Replace box(pic). Thanks

http://pctechtv.com/show/_whatregex.png

Answer (score 1):

```
Match:                           Replace:
#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}[a-fA-F0-9]{3}    #000000
```

This regex searches for a # followed by either 3 or 6 hexadecimal characters (only valid hexadecimal values). There are more exact ways to check, but this is shorter to write.

```
Match:                                 Replace:
rgb\(\d{1,3},\s?\d{1,3},\s?\d{1,3}\)   rgb(0,0,0)
```

This regex looks for the start of a rgb color, up to a 3 digit number, separated by commas, with white-space accounted for after each comma.

Use the "Regular expression" Search Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `\#([0-9]|[a-f]){6}`

Replace: `\#000000`

Find: `rgb\((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\,\s*?){2}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\)`

Replace: `rgb(0, 0, 0)`

(The handy regex snippet `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` means "match a number between 0 and 255 inclusive.")

You'll want to check the "Extended" option in your dialog when you do this.

(Edit: Forgot a couple of characters in the regexes.)

Answer (score 0):

For hex: `\#([0-9]|[a-f]){6}`

For rgb: `rgb\(([0-9]{3},[\s]?)+[0-9]{3}\);`

Hope that helped.